# Is studying philosophy harder than medicine?

Tags: reference-request

If anyone has some kind of experience studying both philosophy and medicine, I would like to know which one was more intimidating and hard to understand.

Comment: I haven't studied medicine, but I'll note that physicians who try to hold forth on philosophy usually sound ignorant, but philosophers who practice medicine would kill people.

Comment: Comparing disciplines of knowledge is like comparing peaches and apples. If you want to pass the tests, both are probably equivalent, you have just to learn the minimum required (which correspond mostly to the time of study). But if you want to learn, both are passionating and wonderful, and you will always find more to learn. There's no one more difficult than the other.

Answer (score 1):

While I have not studied philosophy, I have been to university with both medics and philosophers and have been in a position to compare the challenges both face.

In my opinion they are equally hard, with a different answer possible depending on your definition.  The primary challenge in both subjects is not so much the material, but the other students.

With any subject these days we have spent many years accumulating facts and theories.  Anyone can learn some of them, no one can learn all of them.  The only standard meter we can apply across subjects is "can you get where you want to in your career".  So what really determines difficulty is who else is going for the positions and how many positions there are.  We can look at different stages of the career structure:

- Bachelors degree - philosophy easier

  - At least in the UK there are more positions available for studying a bachelors degree in philosophy than medicine, meaning that the A levels required to get on a philosophy degree are lower than those required for a medicine degree.
- PhD - roughly equal

  - In my limited experience it seems like there are roughly similar opportunities for PhD programs straight out of university for medicine as for philosophy.  This is quite hard to compare accurately, as the medical career path does not require a PhD in the same way as the philosophy career path does, so perhaps I should say this is "within the confidence interval" rather than "equal"
- Getting a job - medicine easier

  - Most medical doctors will be able to work in their chosen field, as there are so many roles that absolutely require a doctor.  Most philosophy graduates will not, as there are fewer roles that require that specific skill set.  Therefore to be a professional philosopher you need to beat more of your colleges than if you want to be a professional doctor.

Answer (score 0):

In medicine, there exist right answers to important questions, as derived from years of accumulated practice in saving *lives*. In philosophy, there are just answers to questions (which are derived from years of accumulated debate over saving *ideas*) that are not always important, and the debate over which are right and which are wrong has no endpoint.